# how to make an uitextfield only accept numbers and commas

Tags: ios, swift, string, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

I have an alertController with UITextField. What I want is that when user enters data in the text field it should only be either numbers or commas. even the decimal point numbers is accepted and whitespaces too are accepted.

e.g. 23,45, 34,25.4,34

in the event of user entering some other character the alert view should give a vibrating shake as a response of incorrect input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use textfield delegate to check if the input character belongs to the accepted character list.

Use this delegate:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

//Have a list with valid characters and check if belongs to that list.
//Return true or false according to validation
return BOOL
```

}